# Design pattern - Python function applied to different objects

Tags: python, numpy, design-patterns, wrapper

I have modified Numpy's [`apply_along_axis()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) function and I want to be able to use this function on different objects (such as `xarray.DataArray` and other multi-dimensional data structures). My modified `apply_along_axis()` coerces the input to a numpy array using [`np.asanyarray()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.asanyarray.html?highlight=asanyarray#numpy.asanyarray). I would like to have a design pattern where i can apply this function to different objects but preserve the meta-data associated with those objects. The meta-data/attributes are now lost because of the coercion to a numpy array.

I do not want to modify the core functionality of `apply_along_axis()` or do type checking on the arguments within `apply_along_axis()`. I want to be able to easily add support for new data structures in the future...  I was thinking of either wrapping the input datastructures or the `apply_along_axis()` function. But I'm not sure how to go about it. Looking for elegant solutions.

Here is the code for the `apply_along_axis()` function:

```
def apply_along_axis(func1d, axis, arr, progress_bar=None, *args, **kwargs):
    '''
    Modified from numpy's apply_along_axis function
    '''

    arr = asanyarray(arr)
    nd = arr.ndim
    # arr, with the iteration axis at the end
    in_dims = list(range(nd))
    inarr_view = np.transpose(arr, in_dims[:axis] + in_dims[axis+1:] + [axis])
    # compute indices for the iteration axes
    inds = iter(ndindex(inarr_view.shape[:-1]))
    # invoke the function on the first item
    try:
        ind0 = next(inds)
    except StopIteration as e:
        raise ValueError(
            'Cannot apply_along_axis when any iteration dimensions are 0'
        ) from None
    res = func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs)
    # build a buffer for storing evaluations of func1d.
    # remove the requested axis, and add the new ones on the end.
    # laid out so that each write is contiguous.
    # for a tuple index inds, buff[inds] = func1d(inarr_view[inds])
    buff = np.zeros(inarr_view.shape[:-1] + res.shape, res.dtype)
    # permutation of axes such that out = buff.transpose(buff_permute)
    buff_dims = list(range(buff.ndim))
    buff_permute = (
        buff_dims[0 : axis] +
        buff_dims[buff.ndim-res.ndim : buff.ndim] +
        buff_dims[axis : buff.ndim-res.ndim]
    ) 
    # save the first result, then compute and save all remaining results
    buff[ind0] = res
    if progress_bar:
        inds = progress_bar(list(inds))
    for ind in inds:
        buff[ind] = func1d(inarr_view[ind], *args, **kwargs)

    # finally, rotate the inserted axes back to where they belong
    return np.transpose(buff, buff_permute)
```

Edit: I realised that the part I left out from the original numpy function might actually be part of the solution. I think i'm looking for a functionality similar to `__array_wrap__`:

```
# wrap the array, to preserve subclasses
buff = res.__array_wrap__(buff)
```

Still not sure how to adapt or write my own `__array_wrap__` to preserve Xarray and other class attributes... Any ideas are welcome

Comment: Seems like you probably should provide the code of the modified function

Comment: Can you highlight the changes you've made - and say why?  In my testing `apply...` is slower than a more explicit iteration, but it may be convenient when the array is 3d or more.  There's a lot of baggage in trying to determine the return array shape and dtype.

Answer (score 0):

Just to highlight a couple of features in the function.

First make a view that has `axis` last:

```
inarr_view = np.transpose(arr, in_dims[:axis] + in_dims[axis+1:] + [axis])
```

Then make an iterator - on all axes except the last one:

```
inds = iter(ndindex(inarr_view.shape[:-1]))
```

This is a trial calculation, used to determine the `dtype` and `shape` of what `func1d` does:

```
res = func1d(inarr_view[ind0], *args, **kwargs)
```

Then it makes an array to receive results:

```
buff = np.zeros(inarr_view.shape[:-1] + res.shape, res.dtype)
```

The work is an iteration over all the `inds` indices:

```
for ind in inds:
    buff[ind] = func1d(inarr_view[ind], *args, **kwargs)
```

where `inarr_view[ind]` is a 1d array.

Imagine `arr` is a 2d array, and we want to pass rows to `func1d`.  We could just do `np.array([func1d(x) for x in arr])`.  That is, just iterate on rows, passing them one at time to `func1d`, and make an array from that.  `apply...` is just a generalization of that pattern.

to illustrate:

```
In [29]: def foo(x):
    ...:     print('x',x)
    ...:     return x**2
    ...: 
In [30]: arr = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [31]: np.apply_along_axis(foo, 1, arr)
x [0 1 2 3]
x [4 5 6 7]
x [ 8  9 10 11]
Out[31]: 
array([[  0,   1,   4,   9],
       [ 16,  25,  36,  49],
       [ 64,  81, 100, 121]])
In [32]: [foo(row) for row in arr]
x [0 1 2 3]
x [4 5 6 7]
x [ 8  9 10 11]
Out[32]: [array([0, 1, 4, 9]), array([16, 25, 36, 49]), array([ 64,  81, 100, 121])]
```

times (without the print):

```
In [35]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(foo, 1, arr)
75.7 µs ± 2.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [36]: timeit np.array([foo(row) for row in arr])
11.4 µs ± 18.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`apply` scales better, and may be faster for large enough arrays.